# fancybox jQuery doesn't function with any other javascript / jQuery scripts?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, fancybox

I have been trying to use other jQuery or javascript scripts in the same page as I use fancybox on but every time I place any other codes in there, the fancybox modal popup stops working and it actually opens a new window instead of the modal!!!

it doesn't matter what and how big or small the new javascript is... it will stop the fancybox functioning correctly but without any other codes in the page, the fancybox functions properly. and I am new to the world of javascript and jquery so I am well lost.

here is my code for fancybox:

```
    <script src="scripts/modernizr-2.6.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        !window.jQuery && document.write('<script src="jquery-1.4.3.min.js"><\/script>');
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./fancybox/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.4.pack.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="modalstyle.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            /*
            *   Examples - images
            */

            $("a#example1").fancybox();

            $("a#example2").fancybox({
                'overlayShow'   : false,
                'transitionIn'  : 'elastic',
                'transitionOut' : 'elastic'
            });

            $("a#example3").fancybox({
                'transitionIn'  : 'none',
                'transitionOut' : 'none'    
            });

            $("a#example4").fancybox({
                'opacity'       : true,
                'overlayShow'   : false,
                'transitionIn'  : 'elastic',
                'transitionOut' : 'none'
            });

            $("a#example5").fancybox();

            $("a#example6").fancybox({
                'titlePosition'     : 'outside',
                'overlayColor'      : '#000',
                'overlayOpacity'    : 0.9
            });

            $("a#example7").fancybox({
                'titlePosition' : 'inside'
            });

            $("a#example8").fancybox({
                'titlePosition' : 'over'
            });

            $("a[rel=example_group]").fancybox({
                'transitionIn'      : 'none',
                'transitionOut'     : 'none',
                'titlePosition'     : 'over',
                'titleFormat'       : function(title, currentArray, currentIndex, currentOpts) {
                    return '<span id="fancybox-title-over">Image ' + (currentIndex + 1) + ' / ' + currentArray.length + (title.length ? ' &nbsp; ' + title : '') + '</span>';
                }
            });

            /*
            *   Examples - various
            */

            $("#various1").fancybox({
                'titlePosition'     : 'inside',
                'transitionIn'      : 'none',
                'transitionOut'     : 'none'
            });

            $("#various2").fancybox();

            $("#various3").fancybox({
                'width'             : '75%',
                'height'            : '75%',
                'autoScale'         : false,
                'transitionIn'      : 'none',
                'transitionOut'     : 'none',
                'type'              : 'iframe'
            });

            $("#various4").fancybox({
                'padding'           : 0,
                'autoScale'         : false,
                'transitionIn'      : 'none',
                'transitionOut'     : 'none'
            });
        });
    </script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(window).load(function(){
        $('#various3').addClass("external").attr({ target: "_blank", href: 'insert.php' })[0].click();
    });
</script>
```

could someone please let me know what i have to do?

Thanks

Comment: Any errors on the console?

Comment: I cannot see any errors! the only thing that happens is that the fancybox modal popup doesn't work and it will open a new window instead. but without any additional javascripts or jQuery codes in the page the fancybox modal works just fine!!

Comment: Check which browser you are using, and google on how to open the console in that browser. When checking the console, you will see an error. There is no problem in Fancybox at all, the problem is that your Javascript is wrong, and thus stops the whole Javascript execution. Using your browser's console, you can find out the problem with your code. Check error messages and learn how to debug. One problem I see now is a `[0]` where it should not be, but there could be others.

Comment: Some help: http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners

Comment: Verify that the other plugins you installed are not loading another version of jQuery (some do) that might create a conflict. Also might sure that you don't load them before loading jQuery. You showed you fancybox code but it would be helpful if you also show how you include your other scripts